# posting image Invalid mime type

Tags: java, android

I am trying to post an image from my galery to the server from my android device.
They are using Python in the back office.

That's what the Back office developper say:
- Django cannot read the file posted by the Android app in request.FILES. iOS does this properly.
- It seems the the Multipart POST does not properly set the key:value required to properly read the requests.

I am getting this error:

> {"errorMessage":"","message":"Invalid mime
>   type","errorCode":0,"success":false}

Any idea why?

Here is my code:

```
public static final String IMAGE_JPEG = "image/jpeg";

private HttpEntity getImageEntity() throws Exception {

            File imageFile;
            Uri originalUri = Uri.parse(this.mFileName);
            String originalPath = originalUri.getPath();
            boolean isEncrypted = originalPath.contains(FileNames.CACHE_DIR.getPath()); 
            // check if file encrypted or not
            if (isEncrypted && ImageLoader.IMAGE_CODING_ENABLED) {
                File originalImageFile = new File(originalPath);
                String decodedPath = CipherUtils.decryptFile(SmartPagerApplication.getInstance(), originalImageFile);
                imageFile = new File(decodedPath);
            } else {
                imageFile = new File(originalPath);
            }

            InputStream fis = imageFile.toURI().toURL().openStream();

            int rotation = PhotoFileUtils.getOrientation(this.mFileName);
            if (rotation > 0) {
                byte[] data;
                Bitmap rotateBitmap = PhotoFileUtils.checkOrientation(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis), rotation);
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                rotateBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                data = stream.toByteArray();
                stream.close();
                rotateBitmap.recycle();
                fis.close();
                fis = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
            } else {
                // data = IOUtils.toByteArray(fis);
            }
            return getMultipartEntity(originalUri, fis);
}

private MultipartEntity getMultipartEntity(Uri originalPath, InputStream fis) {

            InputStreamBody isb = new InputStreamBody(fis, mMimeType, originalPath.getLastPathSegment());

            MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE,
                    "----WebKitFormBoundaryzGJGBFWyGteE24tw", Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));
            multipartEntity.addPart("binaryFile", isb);
            return multipartEntity;
}


private String executePost(String url, HttpEntity params) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
            Log.e("executePost url =" + url);
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary="+"----WebKitFormBoundaryzGJGBFWyGteE24tw");
            httpPost.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            httpPost.setEntity(params);

            String response =  SmartPagerHTTPClient.getHttpClient().execute(httpPost, new BasicResponseHandler());

            return response;
 }
```

Comment: Mime types are listed here: "http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html", the mimetype you should send in the "Content-type" header should be "image/jpeg". Are you really sending that as the content-type header?

Comment: httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");

Comment: I tried it but I still get the same error
{"errorMessage":"","message":"Invalid mime type","errorCode":0,"success":false}

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I have to put this as an answer. In you method getMultipartEntity(), the first line:

```
InputStreamBody isb = new InputStreamBody(fis, mMimeType,  originalPath.getLastPathSegment());
```

What is the value of mMimeType? Please make sure it's a correct mime type.

Comment: public static final String IMAGE_JPEG = "image/jpeg";

Comment: @HaythemSouissi where did you set it, can you verify that at the time of the method being invoked, the value of mMimeType is "image/jpeg"? Or you may replace it with IMAEG_JPEG and have a try again.

Answer (score 2):

This is an OKHttp implementation

first, you need to include it in dependencies:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
```

---

Actual upload code : Call within an Asynctask

```
                    File upload;
                    upload = new File("<<Your Path to image>>");
                    Response response;
                    String finalResponce;
                    try {
                        RequestBody body = new MultipartBuilder()
                                .addFormDataPart("Image", upload.getName(), RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), upload))
                                .build();
                        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                                .url("https://iamin-events.appspot.com/UploadServlet")
                                .post(body)
                                .build();
                        response = new OkHttpClient().newCall(request).execute();
                        finalResponce = response.body().string();
                        finalResponce = finalResponce.trim();
                        mainEventListing.setBackdropUrl(finalResponce);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // show error
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my code for uploading images.The "Content-Type" is like that httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");

```
public String doPutUploadImage(File image) throws Exception {
    String imageUrl = "http://" + Const.BUCKET_NAME
            + ".oss-cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/" + image.getName();
    URL localURL = new URL(imageUrl);

    URLConnection connection = localURL.openConnection();
    HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
    httpConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    httpConnection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
    httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Host",
            Const.BUCKET_NAME.concat(".oss-cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com"));
    String GMTDate = SignatureMaker.getGMTDate();
    if(!GMTDate.contains("+")){
        httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Date", GMTDate);
    }else{
        GMTDate=GMTDate.substring(0, GMTDate.indexOf("+"));
        httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Date", GMTDate);
    }
    httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Encoding", "UTF-8");
    httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
    httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",
            String.valueOf(image.length()));
    httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization",
            "OSS "+ ACCESS_ID+ ":"
                    + SignatureMaker.makeSignature(ACCESS_KEY, "PUT",
                    Const.BUCKET_NAME, image, GMTDate));
    sendRequest(httpConnection, image);
    return imageUrl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `MultipartEntity`, I suggest that you use `MultipartEntityBuilder` with `HttpURLConnection`. Then, you can refer to my following code (pay attention to `ContentType contentType = ContentType.create("image/jpeg");`):

```
...
byte[] bitmapData = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
String address = "http://192.168.1.100/api/postfile";
String boundary = "----apiclient----" + System.currentTimeMillis();
String mimeType = "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary;
MultipartEntityBuilder entityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
entityBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
entityBuilder.setBoundary(boundary);
// Add binary body
if (bitmapData != null) {
    ContentType contentType = ContentType.create("image/jpeg"); //CREATE ContentType for the file part
    String fileName = "some_file_name.jpeg";
    entityBuilder.addBinaryBody("binaryFile", bitmapData, contentType, fileName);
    try {
         URL url = new URL(address);
         HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
         urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
         urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
         urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
         urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", mimeType);
         entityBuilder.build().writeTo(urlConnection.getOutputStream());

         JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
         try {
             if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() < HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST) {
                  // process urlConnection.getInputStream();
             } else {
                  // process urlConnection.getErrorStream();
             }
             jsonObject.put("Message", urlConnection.getResponseMessage());
             jsonObject.put("Length", urlConnection.getContentLength());
             jsonObject.put("Type", urlConnection.getContentType());
         } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }                        
    } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();                            
    }
}
...
```

If you still want to use `MultipartEntityBuilder` with **`HttpPost`**, you can refer to the following:

```
...
byte[] bytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
ContentType contentType = ContentType.create("image/jpeg");
String fileName = "some_filename.jpg";
MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
// Add binary body
builder.addBinaryBody("binaryFile", bytes, contentType, fileName);      
HttpEntity httpEntity = builder.build();
httpPost.setEntity(httpEntity);
...
```

You can find out that **`addBinaryBody`** in **`MultipartEntityBuilder`** class has many implementations such as:

> - public MultipartEntityBuilder addBinaryBody(String name, InputStream    stream, ContentType contentType, String filename)
> - public    MultipartEntityBuilder addBinaryBody(String name, File file,    ContentType contentType, String filename)
> - public    MultipartEntityBuilder addBinaryBody(String name, byte[] b,    ContentType contentType, String filename)
> - ...

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is because you are setting **Content-Type** yourself in code, I once had same issue in my case I just removed the *Content-Type* and It worked. If you remove the Content-Type, you mean that library will **detect** its Content-Type based on its type.

just remove this line

```
httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary="+"----WebKitFormBoundaryzGJGBFWyGteE24tw");
```

Comment: didn't fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i am doing and works fine for me -

```
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
entity.addPart("photo", new FileBody(new File(imagePath), "image/jpeg"));
httppost.setEntity(entity);
```

Comment: this didn't fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [org.apache.http](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/content/FileBody.html) documentation  Change your mime-type static declaration

```
public static final String IMAGE_JPEG = "image/jpeg";
```

to

```
public static final String IMAGE_JPEG = "image/png";
```

In addition to the @BNK answer Instead of MultipartEntity, you can use MultipartEntityBuilder with HttpURLConnection. In that you can upload the image as a binary body and there you can  set the type and the name:

```
multiPartEntityBuilder.addBinaryBody(imageName, byteArray, ContentType.create("image/png"), "image.png");
```

Comment: this didn't fixed my problem. still getting Invalid mime type

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running your code on Android 4.0.x which has buggy implementation for multipart/form-data (httpclient). This [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42639) has been reported earlier and has a work around [here](https://gist.github.com/afchacon/4512953)